# Iphone stuck in start cycle (occasionally enters recovery mode but itunes fails - storage full)

Tags: iphone, itunes, backup, restore, recovery

Have read the other related posts (and must confess to not understanding all technical hacks people have tried), but so far not solved my difficulties.

My iPhone XR is stuck in a restart cycle with just the apple logo on constantly (but every now and then the screen goes black and then relights with the logo again). I have tried the volume up / volume down / side button and it doesn't change things. I have also tried holding the side button down for a minute which mostly does nothing but twice entered the phone into recovery mode (I think that's what it's called where it shows me the connection to a computer with the restore link).

I have tried connecting it to my pc and it can't be found either in iTunes or file explorer. Once, when in recovery and when connected, itunes briefly recognised it and gave me the update/restore option. I tried to update, but it got stuck at the 'iPhone Stuck on ‘support.apple.com/iphone/restore’ loop before ejecting it again. At this time, I still couldn't see it in File Explorer, but could briefly see the apple USB drivers under device manager.

I strongly suspect the root of my problems is that the phone storage is too full (i know, i know). I was trying to delete apps when it crashed. This means that it will be impossible for an itunes update to install, i suspect?

The last backup was in October (again, I know). I am desperate not to lose the data from what has been a horrendous three months. Is there anything else I can try?

I am based in the North East of England, so suggestions to contact drivesavers etc. don't seem to be feasible from here.

Thanks so much!

EDIT
Have tried via 3uTools and tried restoring to old version of iOs - neither has worked :-(
Not sure if there would be value in trying Elcomsoft iOs forensic toolkit? Or less likely now have tried flashing? Will this make data harder to retrieve? What kind of data retrieval can i hope for - a format that would be usable/extractable?!

Comment: There are UK recovery companies too - I found one in Newcastle… though whether they're open right now would be speculation. Restoring the phone from iTunes will definitely wipe it btw.

Comment: Thanks Tetsujin. I haven't found one yet, but will have a look. Have tried (unsuccessfully) flashing, so not sure if this makes these less likely to work?

Comment: 'flashing'?? What's that? It's normally a term used for firmware - but iOS doesn't have any separate firmware component in that way.